# Why does invoking a PowerShell script block with .Invoke() return a collection?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

It seems that invoking a PowerShell script block (by invoking the `.Invoke()` method) always produces a collection.  Specifically, a collection of type

`` System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] ``

Even invoking an empty script block (`{}.Invoke()`) returns a collection.  Invoking the same script block using the call operator (`&`) produces the normally expected return (either a scalar or `[object[]]`).

This turns out to be convenient if you need a collection instead of an array, but it seems kind of counterintuitive.

Does anyone know why it behaves this way?

I knew there are two different invocations, `.Invoke()` and `.InvokeReturnAsIs()` from reading the language spec. That's were I first noticed it.

I just don't understand the reasoning behind the naming convention and the way the mechanics of it appear to work. Looking at the documentation, what I would have thought would be the default invocation method is not what is used when the script block is invoked in PowerShell. It appears that `.InvokeReturnAsIs()` just returns a stream of objects, and then PowerShell wraps it into an object array if there's more than one object, as scalar if there's only one object, or creates a null object if there are none, as if there's an implicit pipeline there. Using `.Invoke()` returns a collection, always, and PowerShell leaves it as a collection.

Answer (score 12):

Looks to be the difference between these two methods:

> **Invoke** - Invokes the script block with the specified arguments,
> returning the results as PSObject objects.
>
> **InvokeReturnAsIs** - Runs the script block with the specified arguments.
> This method returns the raw (unwrapped) result objects so that it can
> be more efficient.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock_methods(v=vs.85).aspx

**Invoke**

```
$code = {"a"}
$code.Invoke().Gettype().FullName
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
```

**InvokeReturnAsIs**

```
$code.InvokeReturnAsIs().GetType().FullName
```

Output:

```
System.String
```

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that the team wanted to be consistent with the [`PowerShell.Invoke()` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns a `Collection<PSObject>`.  This C# signature makes it easier for clients to consume 0, 1 or N returned values and not have to worry about checking for null and whether the returned object was wrapped or not.

From the [.NET Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> DO NOT return null values from collection properties or from methods
>   returning collections. Return an empty collection or an empty array
>   instead.

You could say then why not just return `object`.  Then I would have to against `null` or not and then I'd have to test to see if it implemented `ICollection` to determine if I had a scalar or collection.  From a C# dev's point of view, this is a spew (pardon the rhyme).  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what it is designed to do, and there is an alternate!

`Invoke` -  Invokes the script block with the specified arguments, returning the results as (collection of) PSObject objects.

`InvokeReturnAsIs` -    Runs the script block with the specified arguments. This method returns the raw (unwrapped) result objects so that it can be more efficient.

Also, `{}.invoke()` returns null, so I don't know where you got the impressions that even that returns a collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokereturnasis(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I got the idea that it ruturns as collection when I did this:  ({}.invoke).gettype()

Comment: `Get-Member -InputObject ({}.invoke())` shows that it too returns a collection; conversely, `$null -eq {}.Invoke()` returns `$False`. The collection returned is _empty_, which is why it produces no output in the console.