# PowerShell Invoke returns array instead of int

Tags: powershell

I have the following snippet of PowerShell:

```
$property = @{
    Getter = { 80 };
}

$value = $property.Getter.Invoke() 
$value.GetType() # Shows Name = Collection'1 instead of int
```

I would expect `$value.GetType()` to return `Int32` but instead it returns a collection.

I can't just take element `[0]` because sometimes the Getter function will return an array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Standard tricks for preventing unrolling apply: `(,$value)[0]` will give you the first element of the returned collection (and it always returns a collection, because that's the signature of `ScriptBlock.Invoke()`) without eagerly unrolling it if it's enumerable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does invoking a Powershell script block with .Invoke() return a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028804/why-does-invoking-a-powershell-script-block-with-invoke-return-a-collection): `$property.Getter.InvokeReturnAsIs().GetType()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can strictly declare the type of the return value by this way. For example, the return type will be `Double` :

```
cls
$property = @{
    Getter = [Func[Double]]{ 80 }
}

$value = $property.Getter.Invoke() 
$value.GetType().Name
# Double
```

Comment: To be precise, this doesn't declare a return type as such, it instead makes `Getter` a `Func<double>` instead of a `ScriptBlock`, and thus uses a very different `Invoke` method. This becomes relevant if you wanted to do something else with `Getter` than invoking it (like retrieving the AST).

Comment: btw, you could also simply use the [unary comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators1#comma-operator-): `$property = @{ Getter = ,{ 80 } }`

Comment: @JeroenMostert , @JeroenMostert , `Func<TResult>` **TResult**:The type of the return value.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes, of course the generic parameter is the return type of the `Func` assigned to `Getter`, but this is not the same as declaring the type of the value returned by the script block (e.g. `Getter = { [double] 80 }`, which of course does not resolve the issue because it's still a `ScriptBlock`)). It is important to note that these things are very different semantically, they just happen to both have `Invoke` methods -- `$property.Getter.GetType()` is different in both cases. Note that you can also declare it as `Func[Object]` or even `Func[bool]` -- PowerShell doesn't object to casting.